# Memory increasing when calling IIS related cmdlets in a .ps1 file

Tags: powershell, iis

In C# I have the following code to run a script by text.

---

```
   public virtual void RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            Pipeline pipeline = null;
            RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = null;
            try
            {
                runspace.Open();
                runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

                //create pipeline and run the script
                pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

                pipeline.Invoke();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Log error
            }
            finally
            {
                pipeline.Stop();
                pipeline.Dispose();
                pipeline = null;
                runspace.Close();
                runspace.Dispose();
                runspace = null;
                runSpaceInvoker.Dispose();
            }
}
```

---

And within the script, I'm simply executing the following cmdlet

```
Get-WebsiteState -Name "Default Web Site"
```

---

My memory keeps climbing each time I execute the script.  Granted, this is eventually going to be a part of a larger script that does more than just this one function, but it seems that *any* combination of IIS commands ends up grabbing more and more memory.  I've attempted to:

1. call [System.GC]::Collect() directly in the script
2. Assign Get-WebsiteState -Name "Default Web Site" to a variable, and then
   explicitly call Remove-Variable as well as set it to $null

There are no "Dispose" methods on the results of the IIS cmdlets that I've used.

One thing of note, is that when I execute $PSVersionTable.PSVersion on my machine, it returns 4.0 for my version.

The goal is to be able to use the counters and various elements to display site information to a consumer.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this a misuse of the IIS commands?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of IIS manipulation, I'd recommend looking into using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API directly via `Add-Type C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`

Comment: @Eris I'll look into this.  I'm not going to be recycling servers or adding/deleting websites, but rather, read some basic information about them from their counters/ some of the get cmdlets.  Will this still help with the overhead?

Comment: I would hope so, since you're not spawning new powershell runspaces if you use the direct APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the API directly was the answer.  Still not sure why I can use some cmdlets and not others, but reworking it made it work nicely.